# How to increment a Json Object in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, increment

how to increment an Array of Json?

I have this array, this "jsonObjects" loads a Json from webservice:

```
            arrBusca = [jsonObjects objectForKey:key];
```

If I print this array, results this:

```
2013-03-26 16:50:48.167 teste[6645:907] array 1: (
    {
    idMarca = 118;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = "";
    ordem = 9999;
    tipo = Carro;
    },
    {
    idMarca = 60;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = " -";
    ordem = 2;
    tipo = Carro;
    },
    {
    idMarca = 117;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = "---";
    ordem = 2;
    tipo = Carro;
   }
}
```

And I want to increment this array, so I try:

```
    marcas *myPerson = [[marcas alloc] init];
    myPerson.marca = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fiat %d", i];
    myPerson.idMarca = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
    [arrBusca addObject:myPerson];
```

But the result is:

```
2013-03-26 16:50:48.167 teste[6645:907] array 1: (
    {
    idMarca = 118;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = "";
    ordem = 9999;
    tipo = Carro;
    },
    {
    idMarca = 60;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = " -";
    ordem = 2;
    tipo = Carro;
    },
    {
    idMarca = 117;
    idTipo = 1;
    marca = "---";
    ordem = 2;
    tipo = Carro;
   },
"<marcas: 0x1fd807e0>",
"<marcas: 0x1fd89e40>",
"<marcas: 0x1fd80c90>",
"<marcas: 0x1fd8a1b0>",
"<marcas: 0x1fd8ada0>",
"<marcas: 0x1fd89cb0>",
}
```

Anyone knows how to increment an jsonobject array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide NSCoder methods to archive and unarchive your "`marcas`" objects.

Right now, when you add the objects to your "`arrBusca`" NSMutableArray (it *is* mutable, right?), they're being added as "`marcas`" objects and not the raw non-marcas objects you decoded from JSON).

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I dont know how to make this. I try this, but results the same things =(

https://gist.github.com/filipecrosk/5249188